# Datawarehouse design: fact table for store system alarms

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, olap, etl

I'm a newbie in datawarehousing, but I am in charge of this task.
I need to create a schema (star) to store "Alarms"; so alarms comes from MySQL OLTP database and are a sort of log of access control system.
Alarms have to be recorder because it needs to analyze the history of alarms happened in the past (for maintenace purpose).

My idea is

- DimDate

  - fullDate
  - dayOfMonth
  - dayOfYear
  - dayOfWeek ...
- DimTime

  - fulltime
  - hour
  - minute
  - second
  - ampm
- DimAlarm

  - AlarmSourceID
  - AlarmDescriptionENG
  - AlarmDescriptionITA
  - AlarmDescriptionDEU
  - AlarmDescriptionFRA
- FactAlarm

  - *Foreign keys and nothing more?*

But, now, I don't know what should be the measures on Fact table.
Because an alarm on the source DB is just an ID, a description and a timestamp, but the alarms have to be queryed for all of those farameters.

How is this schema??

Thank you

Comment: Looks OK; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788008/warehouse-store-and-count-non-fact-records/6789847#6789847

Comment: Grab [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247) and read about **degenerate dimensions** (in your case, `ID` that will be stored in `FactAlarm`) and **factless fact tables** (you don't need any measures at all).

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz a bit expanded, your comment would  good answer to the question :-).

Comment: @DamirSudarevic The link is the answer.I also checked in Kimball (as Marek suggested): "Factless fact tables are the preferred method for recording events in a data warehouse where there is no natural numeric measurement associated with the event".